# Symfony: use DataTransformer in formType via Dependency injection

Tags: symfony, service, sonata-admin, transformer-model

I want to use my DataTransformer to convert base64 strings to fileSystem images.

my code:

```
services:
lion_visionomie_media_bundle_base64_data_transformer:
    class: Lion\Visionomie\MediaBundle\Transformer\Base64DataTransformer
    arguments: ['@sonata.media.generator.default', '@sonata.media.manager.media', '@sonata.media.pool', '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']

lion_visionomie_media_bundle_slide_type:
    class: Lion\Visionomie\MediaBundle\Form\SlideType
    arguments: ['@lion_visionomie_media_bundle_base64_data_transformer']
    tags:
        - {name: form.type}

class Base64DataTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
/**
 * @var GeneratorInterface
 */
private $pathGenerator;

/**
 * @var MediaManager
 */
private $mediaManager;

/**
 * @var Pool
 */
private $pool;

/**
 * @var EntityManagerInterface
 */
private $entityManager;

public function __construct(GeneratorInterface $generator, MediaManager $mediaManager, Pool $pool, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    $this->pathGenerator = $generator;
    $this->mediaManager = $mediaManager;
    $this->pool = $pool;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return mixed
 */
public function transform($value)
{
    // [...]
    return $media;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $value
 * @return mixed
 */
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
    /** @var Media $media */
    $media = $value;

    return base64_encode(file_get_contents($media->getPreviousProviderReference()));
}
}

class SlideType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @var Base64DataTransformer
 */
private $base64DataTransformer;

public function __construct(Base64DataTransformer $base64DataTransformer)
{
    dump($base64DataTransformer);
    die;
    $this->base64DataTransformer = $base64DataTransformer;
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('active')
        ->add('background')
            ->addModelTransformer($this->base64DataTransformer)
        ->add('thumbnail')

    ;
}
```

My current problem is, that the base64DataTransformer variable in SlideType is null.

Can you tell me why is this null?

Maybe I can use the ContainerAwareInterface in my SlideType. But I don't want to put my dependencies manually to my DataTransformer Class.

Comment: It seems correct, Once you find out whats wrong you should attach model transformer outside of the builder add chain. 
`$builder->get('background')->addModelTransformer($this->base64DataTransformer);`

Comment: Okay, I tried to create the Form with the FormBuilder in my FOSRestController. Currently I use the ApiDoc Annotations to generate a sandbox to test my REST-Services. I have trouble with the input value: input="Lion\Visionomie\MediaBundle\Form\SlideType"

Now I don't know which Parameters should I pass to my Controller. Additionally I think it's a workaround. Do you think I should Wrap my Form with a custom Class or report it to the symfony dev group?

Comment: I wasn't aware you were using FOSRestBundle, how are you instantiating the form ?

Comment: I create it from the method ->createFormBuilder in FOSRestBundleController and get Form with method getForm()

Comment: It can be the definition of the FormType in the service.yml
I try to implement the ContainerAwareInterface but can't get a instance of container_service due to injection. Symfony version is 2.7.11

Answer (score 0):

If you want to register your form in the DIC with Symfony < 2.8, you should add the `alias: <result of getName()>` parameter to the `form.type` tag of the type. In your case, if `SlideType::getName()` returns `slide`, set the tag to `{ name: form.type, alias: slide }` and make sure that the form is instantiated by passing the name, not the type instance:

```
// good
$form = $this->createForm('slide', ...);

// bad
$form = $this->createForm(new SlideType(), ...);
```